# replace text attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a jquerymobile app, that has this header code

```
@section header
{
@Html.ActionLink("Cancelar", "DocsCancelar", "Docs", new { area = "Documentos" }, new { StrIdDocumento = "", data_icon="delete" })
<h1 id="NombreItem">Ubicacion 50 </h1>
@Html.ActionLink("Grabar", "DocsGuardar", "Docs", new { area = "Documentos",StrIdDocumento = SessionBag.Current.StrIdDocumento }, new { data_icon="check" })
}
```

I want to change the text at

```
<h1>****</h1> tag.
```

I have this jquery function

```
$(data).find('NombreItem').each(function () {
    $('#NombreItem').replaceWith($(this).text());
})
```

But this replace the entire tag, the only thing I need to change is **Ubicacion 50** for **Ubicacion 70** or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do: `$('#NombreItem').text(newText);`

Comment: Fantastic, jquery is really simple but I'm just starting with it.

Comment: What about change an attribute... somethin like change href of an a tag ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez `.attr("href", ...)`

Comment: Excellent very tks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the **Ubicacion** text in a `span` tag with `id="replaceText"`, and then just replace the whole tag?